# How do I equip armor?

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition

In Minecraft: Pocket Edition (on the iPod touch) version 0.6.0, I can now craft armor. The only problem is I do not know how to put it on. How do I equip my armor?

Comment: What edition do you have?

Comment: Oh that explains it. I thought I had to put it on by the same way you eat the food. Lol

Answer (score 4):

You tap your inventory icon. At the top left hand corner it says craft, and next to it it says armor. Just tap the armor you want to wear.

Answer (score 0):

Tap the inventory icon and next to craft it will say armor. Just tap that and then ,when your armor and the picture of you appears, just tap the armor you want to put on.